# Is it possible to hide certain times of day in fullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

In the example of the resource scheduler:

https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/vertical-resource-view.html

Is it possible to hide the times that we are closed and not just shade them out?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `minTime` and `maxTime` options, e.g.

```
minTime: "09:00",
maxTime: "17:00"
```

will only show times between 9am and 5pm each day.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/date-display for further documentation.

Comment: No problem, I should point out that it always pays to make a thorough study of the documentation

Comment: In version v5, use slotMinTime and slotMaxTime

Comment: @BebetoAlves That's fine but this question was about an earlier version, so it's not wrong in that sense.